# Insert data on ethereum blockchain

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, private-blockchain

I have a JSON data. I want to store that data on the ethereum blockchain. I want to share that `transaction_id` of that data to all my users across the world so that anyone can see the data.  How to store the data on the blockchain? Do I have to use gas for storing or Is there any other method that I can store without using ether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store anything on the Ethereum blockchain without paying gas.

To store data, you should create a smart contract. You could hard-code the data in the contract, if you dont ever want it to change:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract DataStore {
    string public jsonData = "{\"aKey\": \"YOUR DATA GOES IN HERE\"}";
}
```

This, however, cannot be done efficiently with large amounts of data. In that case, you had better store a hash of the data in a smart contract. Then, you propagate the real data in another way, like [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) or [Swarm](https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm). Your users can verify that the data is correct by hashing it and comparing that hash with the one you stored in the smart contract.